# How to use onclick and onclicklistener in same program?

Tags: java, android, onclick

I'm having two button in one activity. One button having onclick event & another one is onclicklistener. If i'm going to run my application, it shows force close error. Is there possible to use these two event at the same activity?

Comment: Two buttons can be handled by the same OnClick(). Else you can show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use...

```
public class MyClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener   
{   
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   
{     
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   

    btn1. setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()   
    {    
      public void onClick( View v )   
      {   
        //add action for btn1.   

      }   
   });   

  btn2.setOnClickListener( this );   

}   

public void onClick( View v )   
{   

if( v== (Button)findViewById( R.id.btn2_id )   
{  

  //perform action for btn2. 

}  

}  

}
```

Answer (score 2):

the OnClickListener for all the buttons as follows:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

then add the onClick() event as shown below:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(v == btn1){
//Things to do  
}
if(v == btn2){
    //Things to do      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please sent actual error from logcat.

OR Following code may be help full.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

  public class Test2Activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private Button btn1, btn2;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        System.out.println("Button 1 Press");
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        System.out.println("Button 2 Press");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. (as specified by Uttam) is to implement one `OnClickListener` and add a switch case to distinguish between different buttons.
2. Create a separate anonymous OnClickListeners for each button:

   ```
   btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnclickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // first button behavior
       }
   }

   btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnclickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // second button behavior
       }
   }
   ```